# With GSON, is it possible to get a list of fields in an HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson

I have the following class:

```
public class Address {
 String customerName;
 String emailAddress;
 String address1;
 int age;
 double height;
 // .. etc, including getters and setters

}
```

would it be possible to get an HashMap of those fields somehow? For instance, `String name = address.getFields("customerName");`. It would make validation a lot easier.

Comment: Why would you need a Map of those fields if you already know that they are there? Do you mean that you want to validate the JSON before (de)serializing it to a POJO?

Comment: Basically I have a Fragment that a user submits their address to, and if there's any errors, the server returns a json object with all the fields (and a message like `{address: "Please enter a valid address"}`. Underneath each `EditText` I have an invisible TextView that will be displayed if there are any errors corresponding to that field. Each TextView is tagged with the name of the json field, such as customerName, emailAddress, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to with the following class definition:

```
public class Address extends HashMap<String, Object>{
}
```

Then to use it:

```
String jsonString = "{\n"
    + "  \"customerName\":\"John\",\n"
    + "  \"emailAddress\":\"john@fake.com\",\n"
    + "  \"address1\":\"Fake St.\",\n"
    + "  \"age\": 20,\n"
    + "  \"height\": 5\n"
    + "}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Address address = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Address.class);
String name = (String)address.get("customerName"); // John
int age = (int)address.get("age"); // 5
```

Now, using Gson deserialization this way isn't as useful and it's more useful with the POJO you originally created.

Although, there are some instances where using a `Map` might be more beneficial such as random key/value pairs that you can iterate over.